# __unicode__(self) doesn't get called by logging

Tags: python, logging

Long story short:

```
# this works as expected:
logging.error(my_object.__unicode__())

# this doesn't:
logging.error(my_object)
```

Same result with `__str__(self)`.
Why?

EDIT: `__str__` actually works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logging will call `str()` (which uses `__str__()` which falls back to `__repr__()` when it's not defined). This is because the logging framework is not Unicode safe (i.e. you can get errors when you try to write Unicode to the various logging sinks).

Comment: Not true. Logging will format the message using `str(msg) % args`. In Python 2.x, you should always implement both `__str__()` and `__unicode__` if you want to provide stringify-behavior.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...     def __str__(self):
...         return "foobar"
...
>>> import logging
>>> logging.error(MyClass())
ERROR:root:foobar
```

Works as expected?!